# Anchor Mouse To Every 16 pixels

Tags: vb.net, anchor, mouse

I am making a simple rpg level creator using textures I have made (16x16) for my rpg game engine (pretty much finished except this).

My level designer form adds a picturebox control to the form (with an image of the selected texture) on click. However, I would like to make the mouse move on a grid so it jumps every 16 pixels. For example, if the mouse was at position (0,0), I would like to make the mouse jump to (16,0) when the user moves the mouse right a small bit. Another example: Mouse is at (0,0), user moves mouse down screen so mouse immediately anchors to (0,16) and then the user goes down further and the mouse anchors to (0,32).

Sorry for my explanation but it is very difficult to explain.
Please let me know of any ways to achieve this in VB (prefered) or if there is no way, in c#(deprecated).

Thanks

Rodit

Comment: Seriously, don't do it this way.  Just check if the user is pressing a mouse button and then see which tile the mouse is over and do your work.  Nobody likes the computer moving the mouse for them.  It's a very jarring experience to the end user.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech . I have solved it by using arrow keys instead of the mouse anyway! Thanks for your reply!